# Dynamically change a Windows Form window title (during runtime)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a C# .NET 4.5-based Windows Forms application.

I know how to programmatically modify the title of the main window like this:

```
public partial class MyForm: Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (!PRODUCTION)
        {
            this.Text += " (test environment)";
        }
    }
 }
```

However, all of my research so far has shown that this must be done *before* the form is loaded/shown.  I'd like to be able to change the window title while the app is running, just like a web browser changes its window title to include the name of the current webpage.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: I made a button and in the click event I wrote `this.Text = "Clicked";` and it changed it.

Comment: It looks like `this.Text` works after the form is loaded.  I didn't think that it did work before, but trying it again it does work fine.  I'll close this question.  Sorry for the bother!

Comment: this.Text = "<requred text>";  this should do the work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.Text += " (test environment)";
this.Update();
```

or that:

```
this.Text += " (test environment)";
this.Refresh();
```

You may call those methods in any time you want, not depend of client actions. The difference is that `Update` redraw only `Form` and `Refresh` redraw `Form` and all included controls

Answer (score 3):

Where are you defining and assigning value to `PRODUCTION`? One can change the text on form easily. Check this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Text += "From Ctor";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Text = "New text";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bad example with the PRODUCTION flag.  That's not the issue, as setting the window title there (before the window is loaded) works fine.  I *was* having problems doing it a run-time.

Comment: You can set the Text property of the form whenever you want and it will be reflected when window repaints itself.

Answer (score 0):

the way i do this its changing the text property in the Load Event.  Like this

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = "new title [" + stringvariable + "]";
    }
```